# Почему список созданный функцией распечатывает в квадратных скобках?

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему список созданный функцией распечатывается в квадратных скобках, а созданный вручную без скобок?

```
   from random import randrange as rnd


    def create_random_list(x):
        A=[0]*x
        for i in range(0,x):
            A[i]=[rnd(0,10)]
        return(A)


    B = create_random_list(10)
    for x in B:
        print(x, end='', sep='')

    print()  

    B = [1,2,3]
    for x in B:
        print(x, end='', sep='')
```

Comment: `A[i]=[rnd(0,10)]` - Вы `i`-му элементу присваивает список, содержащий только одно какое-то случайное значение. Уберите `[]` в правой части и получите результат, как с `B = [1,2,3]`.

Comment: *>>почему* - потому что функция возвращает список списков, внутренние списки выводятся как списки (обернуты в `[]`).

Comment: Спасибо! Понял!